# Is there a way to add multiple elements in one line to a python set?

Tags: python, pandas, set

I am iterating over a pandas dataframe and would like to add unique elements to a set from multiple columns of the dataframe. Currently I do it like this:

```
list_a = set([])
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    list_a.add(row.a)
    list_a.add(row.b)
```

I tried this:

```
list_a = set([])
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    list_a.add(row.a, row.b)
```

But it results in the following error message:

```
TypeError: add() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this operation than the way I did it (consider the case when there are more than 2 columns to add values from)?

Comment: I'm confused. A `list_a` is a `set`, you should change that IMO.

Comment: Well...`list_a.add(row.a), list_a.add(row.b)` is one line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC then the following should work:

```
df[['a','b']].stack().unique()
```

Example:

```
In [60]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2,2,3], 'b':np.arange(5), 'c':[-1,2,2,54,6]})
df

Out[60]:
   a  b   c
0  0  0  -1
1  1  1   2
2  2  2   2
3  2  3  54
4  3  4   6

In [61]:    
df[['a','b']].stack().unique()

Out[61]:
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

You can cast to a `set` if necessary:

```
In [63]:
set(df[['a','b']].stack().unique())

Out[63]:
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Union` of sets:

```
list_a = set()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    list_a |= {row.a, row.b}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the union functionality - 
`list_a = list_a.union([row.a, row.b])`

See more on the python sets documentation - https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) method in the `set` data type.

```py
list_a = set()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    list_a.update((row.a, row.b))
```

Comment: Essentially this is the same thing as [Daniele](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34152427/6474744) wrote.